# Google Tag Manager не загружает скрипт

Tags: google-tag-manager

Всем привет, такой вопрос

Добавил Google Менеджер тегов, в head добавил

```
 <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','ТУТ КЛЮЧ');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

в body

```
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=ТУТ КЛЮЧ"
                      height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Страница грузится по 30-40 секунд

В сети браузера (failed)net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, на скрипте gtm.js, что можно сделать?